Custom Widgets Flutter - Viewing variables from outside the widget
I am trying to create a custom widget out of the code below and haven't found a way to do it such that the text displayed on the screen changes after i call the setState function. It just stays as the initial value. I have also tried to view the variables from outside the class after they have changed and haven't been able too.
I have tried to enclose the Container in a widget called CustomDatePicker setting the constructor of the class to initialise the variables but this hasn't worked as i haven't been able to view the variables from where i call the widget in my main file.
Color darkBlueCustom = const Color(0xFF003366);
Color lightBlueCustom = const Color(0xFFadd8e6);
List months = [
    "January",
    "February",
    "March",
    "April",
    "May",
    "June",
    "July",
    "August",
    "September",
    "October",
    "November",
    "December",
  ];


Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
            height: 45,
            color: darkBlueCustom,
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: CupertinoButton(
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                // Display a CupertinoPicker with list of months.
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    clickedMonth = true;
                    _showDialog(
                      CupertinoPicker(
                        magnification: 1.22,
                        squeeze: 1.2,
                        useMagnifier: true,
                        itemExtent: 32.0,
                        // This sets the initial item.
                        scrollController: FixedExtentScrollController(
                          initialItem: selectedMonth,
                        ),
                        // This is called when selected item is changed.
                        onSelectedItemChanged: (int selectedItem) {
                          setState(() {
                            selectedMonth = selectedItem;
                          });
                        },
                        children:
                            List<Widget>.generate(months.length, (int index) {
                          return Center(child: Text(months[index]));
                        }),
                      ),
                    );
                  });
                },
                // This displays the selected Month name.
                child: Text(
                  months[selectedMonth],
                  style: GoogleFonts.ubuntu(
                    textStyle: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: clickedMonth ? Colors.white : Colors.white38,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Text(
            "$title,$selectedMonth,$clickedMonth",
          ),
        ],
      ),
    )

I have tried making the widget like so :
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

Color darkBlueCustom = const Color(0xFF003366);
Color lightBlueCustom = const Color(0xFFadd8e6);


class CustomDatePicker extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final int selectedMonth;
  final bool clickedMonth;

  const CustomDatePicker({
    super.key,
    required this.title,
    required this.selectedMonth,
    required this.clickedMonth,
  });

  @override
  State<CustomDatePicker> createState() => _CustomDatePickerState();
}

class _CustomDatePickerState extends State<CustomDatePicker> {
  List months = [
    "January",
    "February",
    "March",
    "April",
    "May",
    "June",
    "July",
    "August",
    "September",
    "October",
    "November",
    "December",
  ];

  void _showDialog(Widget child) {
    showCupertinoModalPopup<void>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) => Container(
        height: 216,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 6.0),
        // The Bottom margin is provided to align the popup above the system navigation bar.
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(
          bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
        ),
        // Provide a background color for the popup.
        color: CupertinoColors.systemBackground.resolveFrom(context),
        // Use a SafeArea widget to avoid system overlaps.
        child: SafeArea(
          top: false,
          child: child,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String title = widget.title;
    int selectedMonth = widget.selectedMonth;
    bool clickedMonth = widget.clickedMonth;
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
            height: 45,
            color: darkBlueCustom,
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: CupertinoButton(
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                // Display a CupertinoPicker with list of months.
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    clickedMonth = true;
                    _showDialog(
                      CupertinoPicker(
                        magnification: 1.22,
                        squeeze: 1.2,
                        useMagnifier: true,
                        itemExtent: 32.0,
                        // This sets the initial item.
                        scrollController: FixedExtentScrollController(
                          initialItem: selectedMonth,
                        ),
                        // This is called when selected item is changed.
                        onSelectedItemChanged: (int selectedItem) {
                          setState(() {
                            selectedMonth = selectedItem;
                          });
                        },
                        children:
                            List<Widget>.generate(months.length, (int index) {
                          return Center(child: Text(months[index]));
                        }),
                      ),
                    );
                  });
                },
                // This displays the selected month name.
                child: Text(
                  months[selectedMonth],
                  style: GoogleFonts.ubuntu(
                    textStyle: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: clickedMonth ? Colors.white : Colors.white38,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Text(
            "$title,$selectedMonth,$clickedMonth",
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


The parameter selectedMonth passed to the constructor of CustomDatePicker
can only be used to set the initial selection. To avoid confusion, it should rather be named e.g. preSelectedMonth or initiallySelectedMonth.
The state of your widget should be stored within _CustomDatePickerState, say
in a variable called selectedMonth:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

Color darkBlueCustom = const Color(0xFF003366);
Color lightBlueCustom = const Color(0xFFadd8e6);


class CustomDatePicker extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final int preSelectedMonth;
  final bool clickedMonth;  // Can be removed. 

  const CustomDatePicker({
    super.key,
    required this.title,
    required this.preSelectedMonth,
    required this.clickedMonth,  // Can be removed. 
  });

  @override
  State<CustomDatePicker> createState() => _CustomDatePickerState();
}

class _CustomDatePickerState extends State<CustomDatePicker> {
  final List months = [
    "Select a month",  // <--- Added entry to make selection easier. 
    "January",         // Otherwise, January -> 0 and December -> 11
    "February",
    "March",
    "April",
    "May",
    "June",
    "July",
    "August",
    "September",
    "October",
    "November",
    "December",
  ];
  
  int selectedMonth = 0;
  bool hasClickedMonth = false;  //  
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    selectedMonth = widget.preSelectedMonth; // Initialize the widget state
    super.initState();
  }

  void _showDialog(Widget child) {
    showCupertinoModalPopup<void>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) => Container(
        height: 216,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 6.0),
        // The Bottom margin is provided to align the popup above the system navigation bar.
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(
          bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
        ),
        // Provide a background color for the popup.
        color: CupertinoColors.systemBackground.resolveFrom(context),
        // Use a SafeArea widget to avoid system overlaps.
        child: SafeArea(
          top: false,
          child: child,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String title = widget.title;
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
            height: 45,
            color: darkBlueCustom,
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: CupertinoButton(
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                // Display a CupertinoPicker with list of months.
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    hasClickedMonth = true;
                    _showDialog(
                      CupertinoPicker(
                        magnification: 1.22,
                        squeeze: 1.2,
                        useMagnifier: true,
                        itemExtent: 32.0,
                        // This sets the initial item.
                        scrollController: FixedExtentScrollController(
                          initialItem: selectedMonth,
                        ),
                        // This is called when selected item is changed.
                        onSelectedItemChanged: (int selectedItem) {
                          setState(() {
                            selectedMonth = selectedItem;
                            // Store selectedMonth (see state management below)
                          });
                        },
                        children:
                            List<Widget>.generate(months.length, (int index) {
                          return Center(child: Text(months[index]));
                        }),
                      ),
                    );
                  });
                },
                // This displays the selected month name.
                child: Text(
                  months[selectedMonth],
                  style: GoogleFonts.ubuntu(
                    textStyle: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: hasClickedMonth ? Colors.white : Colors.white38,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Text(
            "$title,$selectedMonth,$hasClickedMonth",
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

To access the selected month from outside the widget you will need to store that variable from within the method onSelectedItemChanged. For more details, I recommend reading up on App state management. The info provided includes a list of state management approaches. Personally, I recommend riverpod.

Reply to comment: You might need to familiarize yourself with the concept of ephemeral vs App state. What I meant is that from within the callback onSelectedItemChanged you typically call a function that receives the value and stores it in a different location,
that is still accessible, for example, when you navigate to a different page.
If the value of selectedMonth is needed beyond the lifetime of the app, you could use a local or remote database, or for example shared_preferences. Otherwise, use one of the approaches listed in the first link above.

Hi, thank you for replying. I understand about making the widget now just not accessing the varibles. How would i go about this? I have edited the post will the ful code of my add_car.dart file to show you why i am trying to do this and "clean it up". Many thanks

I couldnt add to original post as is too many characters. please see link below for the full code : "https://sites.google.com/view/addcardart/home"

The variable selectedMonth is not accessible from outside the private class _CustomDatePickerState. For this reason, you have to store the value of selectedMonth in a location of your choosing, from where you can later retrieve it.
